# ASP.NET Mvc - AutoMapper Best Practice - Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I've not looked at the AutoMapper source code yet but was just about to make some changes to an API controller in my solution and had a thought.

The way I like to code is to keep my controller methods as concise as possible, for for instances I make use of a generic Exception attribute to handle `try{}catch{}` scenarios.

So only the code that is absolutely relevant to the controller action is actually in the action method.

So I just arrived at a situation where I need to create an `AutoMapper` map for a method.  I was initially thinking that I would add this (as I have done previously) to the controller constructor so its available immediately.

However, as the controller grows following this pattern may introduce a lot unnecessary `AutoMapper` work depending on the controller action method which is invoked.

Considering controllers are created and destroyed per request this could get expensive.

What are some recommendations around this?  Considering `AutoMapper` is accessed statically I was wondering if it's internals live beyond the request lifetime and it internally checks for an existing map before creating a new one each time `CreateMap()` is invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create your maps (`CreateMap`) once per AppDomain, ideally when this domain starts (`Application_Start`).

Comment: That also makes a lot more sense since I was just looking at the source code for `AutoMapper` and it does indeed live past the request life-time.  Thanks Darin